# Is there a plane+train journey planning service?

Tags: online-resources, europe, planning

Several months ago, I snagged a very cheap flight from London to Brittany (Quimper). I'm trying to persuade some friends to come out at the same time, but as it's much nearer the time, the flights are, well, not nearly so cheap today...

Thanks to our friends at [LoCo2](http://loco2.com/), I know how much it'd cost them to make the journey by train only. (The price comes out slightly more than my advanced flight price, but quite a bit slower). My supposition is that it might be cheaper + quicker if they flew to somewhere in France, then took the train the last bit. However, here's quite a lot of smaller airports that they might fly to, so a manual search isn't looking all that easy.

Are there any sites which allow you to search for a combined flight+train price, where you give a starting + ending city, and it finds connections?

(Basically, I'm after "HiCO2", something that'll give [LoCo2](http://loco2.com/) style train search results, but with one of the legs by plane)

Comment: Heh, if I wasn't so into trains, I would consider building HiCO2 just for the comedy value :)

Answer (score 2):

On occasion, [kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com/) has shown me Eurostar tickets, and indeed I even booked a premiere (or whatever is just above Economy) ticket to Paris once, as it was cheaper than booking direct on the Eurostar site.

A quick look reveals this is still possible.

Flightfox has also had contests in the past where they enter train details if it's cheaper and the buyer has suggested it's an option (or they've asked). Indeed on a ex-YVR flight, people get asked if they'd bus/train to Bellingham/Seattle.  [It's discussed on one of their threads](https://flightfox.com/news/allow-entering-train-connections).

However, I expect you're asking about a worldwide site, and I'd personally venture there's a big **no** for that one, but would be happy to be proven wrong.  Flightfox is probably the closest for that, even if it is pseudo-manual.